# Optimization for 8 puzzle solutions to store in trees structure

Tags: c++, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have a breadth first search to find the best solution to an 8 puzzle.  In order to make sure I don't execute the same function call on the same puzzle move I have created a tree structure. It doesn't store the puzzle, just creates a pathway in the tree for the 9 values for the 9 slots in the puzzle.  Here is the code:

```
static const int NUM_NODES = 9;

class TreeNode
{
public:
    TreeNode *mylist[NUM_NODES];
    TreeNode()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < NUM_NODES; ++x)
            mylist[x] = nullptr;
    }
};

class Tree
{
private:
    TreeNode *mynode;
public:
    Tree()
    {
        mynode = new Node();
    }
    bool checkOrCreate(const Puzzle &p1)
    {
        Node *current_node = mynode;
        bool found = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < PUZZLE_SIZE; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < PUZZLE_SIZE; ++y)
            {
                int index_value = p1.grid[x][y];
                if (current_node->mylist[index_value] == nullptr)
                {
                    found = false;
                    current_node->mylist[index_value] = new Node();
                    current_node = current_node->mylist[index_value];
                }
                else
                    current_node = current_node->mylist[index_value];
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
};

static Node* depth_Limited_Search(Problem &problem, int limit)
{
    mylist.reset();
    return recursive_Depth_Search(&Node(problem.initial_state, nullptr, START), problem, limit);
}
static Node *recursive_Depth_Search(Node *node, Problem &problem, int limit)
{
    if (problem.goal_state == node->state)
        return node;
    else if (limit == 0)
        return nullptr;
    if (mylist.checkOrCreate(node->state)) //if state already exists, delete the node and return nullptr
        return nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<int> xy(node->state.getCoordinates());
    int xOfSpace = xy.get()[0];
    int yOfSpace = xy.get()[1];
    set <Action> actions = problem.actions(node->state); //gets actions
    for (auto it = begin(actions); it != end(actions); ++it)
    {
        Action action = *it;
        Node &child = child_node(problem, *node, action);
        Node *answer = recursive_Depth_Search(&child, problem, limit - 1);
        if (answer != nullptr)
            return answer;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
static Node& child_node(Problem problem, Node &parent, Action action)
{
    Node &child = *(new Node());
    child.state = problem.result(parent.state, action);
    child.parent = &parent;
    child.action = action;
    child.path_cost = parent.path_cost + problem.step_cost(parent.state, action);
    return child;
}

Puzzle& result(const Puzzle &state, Action action)
{
    // return a puzzle in the new state after perfroming action
    Puzzle &new_state = *(new Puzzle(state));
    int r = state.getCoordinates()[0], c = state.getCoordinates()[1];
    if (action == UP)
        new_state.swap(r, c, r - 1, c);
    else if (action == RIGHT)
        new_state.swap(r, c, r, c + 1);
    else if (action == DOWN)
        new_state.swap(r, c, r + 1, c);
    else if (action == LEFT)
        new_state.swap(r, c, r, c - 1);
    return new_state;
}
```

I've used this on breadth and also on depth limited search using recursion to solve. Using this structure to store all the possible solutions for these algorithms takes a long time. I believe it has something to do with the allocation taking time. Is that the reason? I was thinking of trying to just create a lump of memory, and then assigning a node that address of memory instead of letting the program do it. Would that be the best solution, and how would I do that? (Since I've used this on multiple searches and they all take a long time to perform I haven't included that code.)

Comment: What is the objective of your code? Find the optimal solution? Find a solution? Find all solution for a given initial state?

Comment: That code isn't executable as it is. Please provide a *complete* example, in this case also including the actual solver and a functional stub of the `Puzzle` class.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to use this structure, and make it faster. I wouldn't mind finding an optimal solution to the problem as well.

Comment: Added the depth limited search, but not breadth.

Comment: Also look up "memoization" as a way to avoid re-computing an identical sub-problem.